# If $A$ is an upper-triangular matrix of size $N$, how many multiplications/divisions are necessary to solve $Ax = y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I need help understanding the solution. Here it is:

*Solution. Starting from the last row, one has $x_{N} = y_{N}/A_{NN}$, which requires one division. At row number $i$, one has $x_{i} = (y_{i} - \sum_{j=i+1}^{N} A_{ij} x_{j})/A_{ii}$, which is one division and $N - i$ multiplications. This gives $N$ divisions and $\sum_{i=1}^{N} (N - i) = \sum_{k=0}^{N - 1} k N(N - 1)/2$ multiplications for a total of $N^{2}/2 + N/2$*

---

First of all, I don't really get their notation. What is $x_{N}$ and $y_{N}$? Why are they dividing? Can't they just multiply $Ax$ to get $y$? I got that this requires $1N + 2N + 3N + \cdots + N \cdot N$ total steps.

Can someone please clarify?

Thanks

Comment: They are solving $Ax=y$ for $x$, given $y$, not the other way around.

Comment: The $x_i$ and $y_i$ are just the components of the vectors $\bf x$ and $\bf y$. So $x_N$ and $y_N$ are the last components of them.